# Having problems sending data using AJAX to my DB in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, submit

I've been researching how to send AJAX requests using Laravel and am not getting anywhere. AJAX seems to work as when I remove my on submit/click functions and just say "alert('test') it pops up among clicking the button. However, when I click the "Confirm" button my route is not being called that requests the input from my textarea so therefore the update is not being made when I check my MYSQL database.

I've made sure to enclude CSRF headers on my form and AJAX as well as setting my button type to "button" to prevent a the actual form from being submitted. Can somebody please point me in the right direction whether it's my AJAX, Controller or Web route code that is the cause of my problem. I've been trying to find a fix for the past 2 days and am not succeeding at all. Also there is a one to many relationship between the ticket and reply, so that's why I am accessing a given tickets reply and updating it accordingly. I've also already tried not sending it as JSON and still doesn't work.

This is my form markup:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="edit-reply">
@csrf
@method('PATCH')
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control testing" id="edit-box" rows="12"name="edit-message"                                                              placeholder="{{$r->message}}" required></textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark" id="edit-button" data-dismiss="modal"style="font-weight: bold;">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Markup for AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#edit-button').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
$.ajax({
url: "{{ route('ticket.create', $slug->slug) }}",
type: 'PATCH',
data: {
message: jQuery('#edit-box').val()
},
success: function (result) {
jQuery('.alert').show();
jQuery('.alert').html(result.success);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

TicketController

```
public function editReply(Ticket $ticket)
    {
        $t = $ticket->reply()->update(request(['edit_message']));
        return response()->json($t);
}
```

Code for the route

```
Route::patch('ticket/{ticket}', 'TicketController@editReply')->name('ticket.edit-reply');
```

Comment: Your form data contains `message` as its key. But, you're trying to retrieve it as `edit_message` in your controller.

Comment: @Chay22 Hi, okay so if I were to access that "message" key in my controller, is that possible? or how else should it be accessed? and does me returning it in JSON make any affect?

Comment: Change your ajax type to either get or post same as in laravel route can i have look at your controller how are you getting data and returning it

Comment: Okay and do you want me to send you my entire controller or route:list? So my TicketController above is how I'm trying to return it however I don't think I need to return it as JSON necessarily?

Comment: I had issue with PATCH once. You're gonna have to debug. Are you requesting from different server than the Laravel Server? That could be the problem. Anyway, if you just return `return response()->json($ticket);` just to see, did it return something? If not look like your PATCH request is not sent at all. Open inspect element and go to console tab, you should see the reason why any request might fail. If you have that same problem that I had, I'll help you

Comment: And after `success: function($result)` you might need to catch the error too to see what happened : 
`error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
      console.log(jqXHR.status +' - ' + exception);
}`

Comment: You can use `alert(jqXHR.status +' - ' + exception);` too if you want instead of `console.log()`. But with console logging you need to go to DevTools with a right click and choosing "Inspect"

Comment: Also try with POST or PUT in `type: 'PATCH',`, and `Route::post('ticket/{ticket}'`. to see if it's a problem with PATCH so you'll know what to resolve

Comment: Hi Keitel, I've noticed its a problem with patch because POST abnormally submits data and uses my other post ROUTE instead of the update reply one. Also I did have an error when looking at console but that was because I didn't have the csrf in the meta head (which I have included on this blade view)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass header like this may be its works:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
   headers:{ 
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Ah turns out the problem was because I wasn't using the ajax mesasge key on my controller. However, my only problem now is stopping the submit from updating every message and only the specifc message.